# Capture facebook access token on url is not working now

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I access

```
  http://m.facebook.com/dialog/auth?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=email
```

it's redirect to `www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token={token}&expired={expiredtime}` contain access token code. But this url redirect only appear on few second until page load complete the url is redirect again to `www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html`. The reason I can't capture access token code if redirect to blank url.

Now, how I get/capture access token code without redirect to `www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html` ?
Can I implemented it to javascript with timing function to stop second redirecting?

Comment: If that used to work before and now doesn’t, you should file a bug report.

Comment: The facebook is very slow in responding, so I prefer to ask here. I think it just needs to be a trick to stop loading at the time of accessing the link and stop loading the page before loading process stops. Probably could use javascript but the problem is I do not know how to make that trick in javascript

Comment: AgusSayyupoenya, I'm sorry to hear that we've been slow in responding to your bug report. Could you provide the bug report you created and will make sure it will be looked at. As mentioned by @CBroe, if this used to work then you shouldn't try to workaround the current flow as this might break your app but instead let us know to fix the issue (if any).